# Find the mode of an unsorted array and if that array has more than one mode or no mode

Tags: c++, arrays, nested-loops

I am trying to figure out how I would go about finding the mode of an unsorted array, if that unsorted array has a mode to begin with, or if it has a more than one mode (i.e. 2,2,3,3,4,6,7 in which the modes would be 2 and 3).

I am trying to figure out how to do this without sorting the array before hand.

Currently, I have this:

```
int counter = 1;
int counterTwo = 0;
int mode = array[0];

for (int i = 0; i < SIZE - 1; i++)
{
    if (array[i] == array[i + 1])
    {
        counter++;
        if (counter > counterTwo)
        {
            counterTwo = counter;
            mode = array[i];                
        }
        else
        {
            counter = 1; // Reset counter
        }
    }
}
cout << "\nThe mode is: " << mode << endl;
```

Which sort of does the job but doesn't help me with determining if the array has more than one mode. When there isn't a mode, then it just outputs the first value in the array.

Any help on this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use the [std::adjacent_find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) function.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could without changing your algorithm is to do a first iteration to get the mode count, and then do another iteration to get all elements that are repeated that number of times.

Another algorithm you could use is to save a histogram of each number and its number of occurrences. This could be implemented by c++ `map`, which saves key-value pairs of data. While filing the `map`, you could also save the mode count, and then iterate over the map to get elements with that count.

#### Sample Code

```
int count = 7;
int array[] = {2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6, 7};

std::map<int, int> histogram;

int mode_count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  int element = array[i];
  histogram[element]++;
  mode_count = std::max(mode_count, histogram[element]);
}

for (auto element : histogram) {
  if (element.second == mode_count) {
    printf("%d -> %d\n", element.first, element.second);
  }
}
```